# How to disable pen mode change on slow motion?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, pen

If I try to draw something carefully in OneNote, my pen stops drawing.

I.e. when I start to draw and move pen slowly, some guesture triggers, round circle appears and the line I drew turns to selection border and pen starts to continue selecting process. I.e. my work is dropped as Microsoft likes to do.

[image]

[image]

How to overcome?

How to disable this specific reaction?

I have all checks on in OneNote setup

[image]

Disabling last option does not help.

My press and hold options are set to longest

[image]

My pen is Wacom Bamboo Pen CTL-470

My OneNote is 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Unchecking "enable press and hold for right-clicking" in the Press and Hold Settings worked for me.

Running windows 7 pro, OneNote 2013, Wacom Bamboo Capture tablet.